# Bringing numbers in a set closer together

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I'm trying to express the relative scale of items compared to an "average" scale for all items in the set. This produces values like { 0.5, 1.8, 0.3, 1.2 ... }

I then wish to use this number to visually transform the items so that items that had a smaller relative scale grow somewhat and larger items shrink. Something along the lines of new_size = old_size / scale.

However, this produces too extreme of a transformation. I need to "dampen" this scale value by a controllable amount. So scales < 1.0 would get bigger (but not exceed 1.0) and scales > 1.0 would get smaller (but not be less than 1.0), and an item whose relative scale was 1.0 would remain 1.0.

There must be an easy way to do this, but my math skills are insufficient to the task.

If possible, please express your answer in algorithmic form, since this will be incorporated into a software solution.

Comment: What exactly then are your criteria for a satisfactory scale? What do you mean when you say that the transformation is too extreme?  The more specific you can be about the context, the more we'll be able to help

Comment: A frequent measure of variation is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the average of all your numbers, call it $A$.  Then given a number $x$ you can adjust its distance from $A$ by scale factor $s$, so $x \to A+s(x-A)$  If you let $s=\frac 23$ the distance from the average will shrink to $\frac 23$ of its previous value.  The average will not change.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm having trouble understanding how to translate the mathematical notation to computer code, but that just exposes my own ignorance of math notation.

Comment: In Python, if the numbers are in list, sum=0; for i in list: sum+=i; A=sum/len(list); for n in range(len(list)): list[n]=A+s*(list[n]-A) where the ; should be linebreaks

Comment: Thanks for the extra code! My answer worked for me in my specific situation, but your answer is far better (and more appropriate for a Math SE). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Boy, this was simpler than I thought.

m = ( ( n - 1 ) / d ) + 1;

where 'd' here is the "dampening amount". My mistake was not seeing that "1" was just my offset from 0. Everything works when the offset is 0, so we shift the number down by the offset and then after the dampening transformation, shift it back up.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This shrinks the distance from $1$ as you say.  Do you know that you always want to get closer to $1$ instead of closer to $2$?  That is why I suggested the average.  But if this works for you, go for it.

Comment: thanks for the comment @RossMillikan. I think that -1 + 1 in the equation would represent my middle line. So if I need to get closer to 2 instead of 1, I believe I could substitute 2 instead of 1 in the equation above.

Comment: That is right.  I was using the average to be your middle line.